# Gate Drive Circuit of an AC Voltage Controller

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, thyristor

[image: Gate Control Circuit]

The circuit shown is used to control the gate drive of an AC Voltage Controller. I am trying to understand the functions of each of the parts and cannot understand the need of the NPN transistors Q1 and Q2. The output of the zero crossing detector should be either +5V or -5V. This is then passed through a diode, D1 which is supposed to chop off the negative part. However, I think that even if the transistor, Q1, were absent, the diode D1 would have accomplished the same task and vice versa. What is it that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

U3a is an integrator configured as a sawtooth generator. The ramp rate is determined by the voltage on the wiper of R9 and the combination of R11 and C1. Without studying it in great detail I guess that it generates a ramp which is reset on each zero-cross by Q1. Note that the input voltage is negative and the integrator is inverting so the output will be a positive-going ramp.

Q1's function is to discharge C1, the integrating capacitor. When turned on it will connect U3a's output to the virtual ground at the inverting input which will tend to pull the input in the positive direction. The op-amp will react by rapidly driving the output down until output and input are at zero volts. This creates the vertical edge of the sawtooth.

On positive half-cycles at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3FXW.png) D1 will conduct and Q1 will hold C1 discharged for that half-cycle. When [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3FXW.png) goes negative D1 and Q1 don't conduct and the ramp can begin again. You'll get a ramp on each positive half-cycle and 0 V  at [4] during the negative half-cycles.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvBdEg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simulation circuit.*

[image]

*Figure 2. AC signal, zero-cross signal (actually an AC polarity signal) and the output ramp.*